# CakePHP debug() isn't working but Debugger::dump() is fine

Tags: cakephp

Ever since PHP4 and Cake 1.3 I have been using `debug($data);` to debug things such as model output in CakePHP.

However, since upgrading to PHP5.4, I have noticed that `debug($data)` doesn't always seem to work. For example, today I did a straightforward `$data = $this->Model->find('all');` and the contents of `debug($data);` appears to be empty. No error, just a reference in the HTML output to the fact that I called debug and the line number and then no debug output.

However, if I run `Debugger::dump($data);` on the exact same find, it works find and I see the entire output.

It seems to only be happening when `$data` has a significant amount of data (say, 100+ records), but I worked with datasets this size prior to PHP5.4 and there was never a problem and there are no errors, inline or in the apache/php logs indicating that there are any memory issues and I have debugging set to 3.

Does anyone have any idea why this is? I can obviosly starting using `Debugger::dump($data);` easily but it's just a little extra to have to try out each time and I'd like to know why I can't just use `deubg();` anymore.

Comment: I sometimes see this happening with strange encodings for some records (non utf8 usually). then debug() output is empty whereas vardump() and others work fine. Maybe that is the case here, as well?

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right. The PHP upgrade was just a coincidence. The real reason this is happening is due to presence of newly-added UTF data in the array. Thanks! Feel free to add this as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can happen with non-utf8 encoded data in your db records - if the rest of your application is UTF-8 that is.
`debug()` will then just output "nothing". `var_dump()`, `print_r()` and other php internal methods should still print the output, though.

You can usually re-encode them to utf8 using iconv() etc.