# Cakephp debug not showing data while print_r showing data

Tags: php, debugging, cakephp

i am new to cakephp please help me

here is my code for controller

```
public function getCity() 
{
    $this->autoRender = false;
    //$cities = array();

    $this->loadModel('City');
    //debug($this->request['data']['id']);exit;
    if (isset($this->data['id'])) 
    {
        $cities = $this->City->find("list",array("conditions"=>array("City.state_id"=>$this->data['id']),"fields"=>array("City.id","City.city_name")));

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($cities);
        debug($cities);
        exit;
        echo json_encode($cities);  
    }

}
```

and output for this ajax call function is as below

```
<pre>Array(
[509] => Zwickau
[13402] => Adorf, Vogtland
[13552] => Altenberg, Erzgebirge
[15594] => Diera-Zehren
[15646] => Dippoldiswalde
[17924] => Hartmannsdorf bei Chemnitz
[17926] => Hartmannsdorf bei Kirchberg
[18115] => Heinsdorfergrund
[22731] => Rackwitz
[24976] => Tiefenbach, Sachsen
[24995] => Tirpersdorf
[25025] => Torgau
[25062] => Trebendorf bei Wei�wasser
[25067] => Trebsen / Mulde
[25084] => Treuen, Vogtland
[25088] => Triebel / Vogtland
[25090] => Triebischtal
[26669] => Zschorlau
[26690] => Zwenkau
[26691] => Zwickau
[26697] => Zwochau bei Delitzsch
[26698] => Zw�nitz
[26699] => Zwota
[151788] => Raschau-Markersbach ) 

<div class="cake-debug-output"><span><strong>\app\Controller\SubscribersController.php</strong> (line <strong>919</strong>)</span><pre class="cake-debug"></pre></div>
```

now problem is getting data in print_r function but debug not showing that data...for `City.city_name` field but it showing data in another field like `population`etc...so i am not getting this data in view ....please help me...

Comment: "Zw�nitz" indicates the encoding your php application is different than the data. Possible duplicate of [CakePHP debug() isn't working but Debugger::dump() is fine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433774/cakephp-debug-isnt-working-but-debuggerdump-is-fine)

Answer (score 0):

Just before you do pr, you could write this:

```
echo Configure::read();
```

If it comes as 0, then do the following modification:

Go to Config/core.php and make the value of debug as 2.

```
Configure::write('debug', 2); // Check if it's set to 0.
```

Comment: Configure::write('debug', 2);  is value of debug in config/core.php already

Comment: debug is not working in city_name field while in another field its working...and i need that city_name feild

Comment: This should have been a comment, `<div class="cake-debug-output"><span><strong>\app...` is present in the question indicating the debug is not set to 0.