# debug doesn't work in cakephp 3.0

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

A simple debug($var) in my project doesn't seem to work. I have put the debug($var) inside controller. I am trying to get a variable printed to see what values are assigned. So I try debug($var) but doesn't do anything. The debugtoolkit panel shows up I don't see the variable printed.

I am using cakephp 3.0 I have enabled debug by doing this debug' => filter_var(env('DEBUG', true), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN) in my app.php inside config file.

What could be wrong?

Can someone guide me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433774/cakephp-debug-isnt-working-but-debuggerdump-is-fine ? If print_r() works fine, that might be the case.

Comment: Are you sure it is not working? If you have a css fixed header than it might be under that, so it can be there but not visible.

Comment: try dd($var); if it works it means that you debug message is probably hidden by a visual element (div, picture, ....)

Comment: Are you sure debugging is even enabled? If the DEBUG environment variable is set to 0, that will disable it.

Comment: @GregSchmidt: Where do you check debug environment variable?

Comment: In your app.php, you could echo the value of it, for example. Just echo that and then exit, and you'll see very quickly.